# Statistical significance of repeated cross validation

Tags: statistical-significance, cross-validation, model-evaluation, unbalanced-classes

I'm building a risk model for predicting risk of event within a specific time horizon for some patients. I use ROC-AUC score to evaluate the model. My dataset is highly imbalanced (15 events within 570 patients in the most imbalanced group) and because it consists of real patients there is high variability when resampling from the dataset. So a simple cross validation doesn't provide a good estimation of the performance of the model.

To solve this problem, I use 200 repeats of 3 fold cross validation (or 4 fold cross validation if I have more than 20 events in the specific group in the dataset) and the ROC-AUC scores that are produced have distributions like the one in the image below:
[image: distribution of ROC-AUC scores for 200 repeats of 3 fold cross validation]

I then use these distributions to compute 95% CI of the mean value of ROC-AUC using the `stats.bayes_mvs()` function from the scipy package after applying a box-cox transformation.

My work was accepted at a health informatics conference but one of the reviewers commented that by using 200 repeats of cross validation, the results lose statistical significance and I should stick to using 5 repeats of 5 fold cross validation. I really can't understand why that would be the case. Can anyone provide any information or any idea on why repeating the cross validation would decrease the statistical significance of the results?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! You are right to be skeptical of what that reviewer wrote; it makes no sense to me. I suppose the reviewer could mean that, given a large enough sample size, even tiny (practically insignificant) differences can be statistically significant, but that seems like a weak argument against your methodology (if that's even the argument). // From the incomplete picture you have given about your work, I have my own reservations about your methodology, but, a complete picture might allay those concerns. Nonetheless, congrats on the acceptance!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment @Dave I would love to read you reservations if you have the time to write them

Comment: $1)$ There appears to be a time issue. Are you doing cross validation that accounts for any time series issues? $2)$ What are you doing with the Box-Cox transform and why? $3)$ How do you decide on using three- or four-fold cross validation? $4)$ As Frank Harrell has argued many times (don't have a link right now), ROCAUC is not as good of a metric as its common use suggests. $5)$ I don't know what `stats.bayes_mvs` does or why you're using it. $6)$ There is a violation of a common $iid$ assumption when you do cross validation. $//$ Each of these perhaps warrants its own posted question.

Comment: 1)The time issue is ignored and the problem is solved as a classification problem. I know it is not perfect but that is the best we could do, considering the limitations of the dataset. 2),5) The  stats.bayes_mvs computes Bayesian confidence intervals for the mean. 3) I decided between using 3 or 4 fold based on having enough events. Not using any specific rule (not aware of any :)). 4) I know about the limitations of ROC-AUC but that's what the clinician wanted so... //6) That's a problem I am fully aware of and I wish I had a solution and here's where I was expecting criticism